# Progress monitoring for recursive task on file system

Tags: recursion, filesystems

I have an existing piece of code that scans through a directory recursively, and then decodes and loads information from supported filetypes. This works fine.

The problem is that this process can take a long time to perform, so I'm trying to find a way to do progress reporting. (% complete and estimated time remaining)

There is a conceptual problem though:

- I don't know in advance how many subfolders and files there are. This could be huge.
- I don't know in advance what the structure of the folders is.
- Scanning through the entire folder recursively can potentially take very long.

My initial thought would be to go over all the folders and count how many files there are, and then do progress reporting based on this number. This poses problems for large file-structures (with millions of files and folders).

Alternatively, I though of counting progress as I go. Adding files to my total counted files as I'm going over the directories. But this means that progress can go both up and down, as new files/folders are discovered. My progress would be meaningless as a single large enough folder could reduce my progress significantly.

Is there an alternative solution to this conceptual problem? Perhaps some form of a hybrid solution?

I'm using Java, should that matter. (Though I don't know how it would)

Answer (score 0):

**Stochastic Estimation**

You can also do a depth-first search and *estimate* the remaining work, updating the estimate as you progress.  Simply average the fan-out ratio at each level, and apply those statistics to every unknown folder.  This is hardly perfect, and you might want to be sensitive to some power-law distribution of real-world organizations (i.e. the log of the number of files in a folder will tend to be normally (Gaussian) distributed).

However, this is still subject to fluctuations.  If the first leaf contains 1,000 target files (and is under a large fan-out) and the rest of the tree has only 0-5 per leaf, your initial estimate will be quite high.  If the order is reversed, you'll have an artificially low estimate, until the final 0.1% takes half the actual running time.

**Full Count**

Does it take you so long to count the entries in a large file system?  This would be compared to the load-decode stages.  Is it worth that overhead to give a more accurate progress report?  Remember, you don't have to interpret every file name.  Just count the quantity of target files and then recur on every directory's nodeID.  Deal with those node IDs (integers) rather than the overhead of string names, if you can.